# Swift: Realm error at init "NULL is not supported as an RLMObject property". But I don't have a NULL

Tags: swift, properties, realm

It seems most people with this error are trying to create null strings. I just have three properties

```
dynamic var babyEvent: Int
dynamic var eventDate: NSDate
dynamic var timeSpent: Int
```

which are initialized in init() to

```
override init()
{
    self.babyEvent = BabyWet
    self.eventDate = NSDate()
    self.timeSpent = 5
    super.init()
}
```

but by the time super.init() is called I get 
'(null)' is not supported as an RLMObject property.

There are two Ints and one NSDate, all of which are valid Realm property types. So why am I getting this error?

Comment: Super calls should normally always be the first thing to be called in most OO languages. Is super.init() expecting any data?

Comment: I thought so too but, doing the super.init() call first results in compile time error. "property" is not initialized at super.init() call.

Comment: @user3427079 Swift is different, you can't call out of the initialiser until all the local properties are initialised, hence the call to super after local properties have their values set.

Comment: Maybe the super needs something to initialize with? Like super.init(expectedData). Isn't there an API where you can check if there is a default constructor?

Comment: Thanks Anorak. This stuff looks pretty cool.

Comment: Is this the init of your RLMObject subclass? If you just want these values as starting values for every instance you can set that straight in the definitions: dynamic var timeSpent: Int = 5

Comment: You may want to post your entire class definition, the code that instantiates the class and which version of Realm you are using.  I have created a class with the same properties and was able to instantiate it and save it to Realm without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Realm doesn't support Swift enum's with no raw value. But adding a raw type to the `BabyEvent` enum and assigning the raw value to your realm objects works:

```
enum BabyEvent: Int {
  case BabyWet, case BabyDry
}
class MyRealmObject: RLMObject {
  dynamic var babyEvent = BabyEvent.BabyWet.rawValue
  dynamic var eventDate = NSDate()
  dynamic var timeSpent = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift Enums have a specific type. So while you think you are passing an Int for `BabyWet` you are actually passing something of that specific type.

It seems that you have an Enum for the BabyEvent, so you should really have a look at the `rawValue` property:

```
self.babyEvent = BabyWet.rawValue
```

Comment: BabyWet is define as "let BabyWet = 1" I used to have an enum and it was called out early by Realm as not a valid Realm type, so I changed it. Currently BabyWet has no rawValue property I can use.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote, you can just set the starting values in the model definitions:

```
class TestClass: RLMObject {
    dynamic var babyEvent: Int = 1
    dynamic var eventDate: NSDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var timeSpent: Int = 5    
}
```

but this also works for me:

```
class TestClass: RLMObject {
    dynamic var babyEvent: Int
    dynamic var eventDate: NSDate
    dynamic var timeSpent: Int

    override init() {
        babyEvent = 1
        eventDate = NSDate()
        timeSpent = 5
        super.init()
    }
}
```

In both cases I simply use

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

var myTestObject = TestClass()

realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.addObject(myTestObject)
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

to create and add the object to the Realm.